# Corona Simulator Syntax Error (Unexpected Symbol)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am making a Lua app. Here is the main.lua code:

(This is on Mac.)

```
display.setStatusBar (display.HiddenStatusBar)
local main.lua = require ("main.lua")             --[LINE WITH ERROR]
local director = require ("director")
local mainGroup = display.newGroup()

local function main()
    mainGroup:insert(director.directorView)
    director:changeScene("mainPage")
    return true
end

main()
```

And here is my error report after, it is pretty simple, but I'm not sure what it is about:

```
Corona Simulator Syntax Error

File: /Users/[my computer name]/Desktop/Corona App/main.lua
Line: 4

Unexpected symbol near '.'
```

Comment: I erased that line, then got 2 error reports. :0

Comment: Module 'sprite' not found:resource (sprite.lu) does not exist in archive
 no field package.preload['sprite']
 no file '/Users/christopherujhazy/Library/Application Support/Corona/Simulator/Plugins/sprite.lua'
 no file '/Users/christopherujhazy/Desktop/Corona App/sprite.lua'
 no file '/Applications/CoronaSDK/Corona Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/sprite.lua'
 no file '/Users/christopherujhazy/Library/Application Support/Corona/Simulator/Plugins/sprite.dylib'
 no file './sprite.dylib'
 no file '/Applications/CoronaSDK/Corona Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/sprite.dylib'

Comment: And the other: File: ...rs/christopherujhazy/Desktop/Corona App/director.lua
Line: 135

ERROR: table expected. If this is a function call, you might have used '.' instead of ':'

Comment: stack traceback:
 [C]: ?
 [C]: in function 'insert'
 ...rs/christopherujhazy/Desktop/Corona App/director.lua:135: in function '_listener'
 ?: in function <?:141>
 ?: in function <?:218> (Sorry for the long comments.)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for locals is `local <simple-name>`. So, `main.lua` is not allowed here.

Comment: I got 2 error reports, which I accidentally put above your answer. You can find them on this page above. -CodingInLua

Comment: I actually didn't have the require main.lua in the original code, it just seemed to simplify the error reports by a LOT, so I just went with it. If there is another solution, please say so. Thanks, CodingInLua

Answer (score 3):

You just need to do as follows (in your main.lua):

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
local director=require("director")
local maingroup=display.newGroup()
maingroup:insert(director.directorView)
director:changeScene("yourFirstScene")
return maingroup
```

**Note:** Make sure that `director.lua` and `yourFirstScene.lua` are present in the same folder where your `main.lua` exists

Keep Coding.......... :)

Comment: When it was working, I had a main() and then an end after the lines you put. Would this affect the program?

Comment: Are you mentioning about the call `main()` in your code? It wont affect. It indicates only the function call of `main()`. If you are doing like what I've given above, then no need to add that `main()` , because here I'm calling the next page directly, instead of adding it inside an another function... :)

Comment: It says '<eof>' expected near 'local' on the line that says local maingroup=display.newGroup() I know it means end of file, but how do i stop it?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There was an error in the last line of my answer. Change `return main group` to `return maingroup` [no gap between main and group. It was an error occurred due to auto correction of grammar, sorry, and keep coding..... :) ].

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, I get the same error reports. I will probably turn this into an entire question so more people can try to help also.

Comment: Just comment the line `director:changeScene("yourFirstScene")` and run the app, is the error still exist? If not, then it may be an issue with your next class(i.e..: `yourFirstScene.lua`).

Answer (score 1):

Do not write:

```
local main.lua = require ("main.lua") -- as 'lhf' said.
```

If you are using director class, then as `krs` said, you need to only add the following lines to main.lua:

```
  local director=require("director")  -- import director class(make sure the class exist)
  local parentGroup=display.newGroup() -- create new display group namely 'parentGroup'
  parentGroup:insert(director.directorView) -- insert director view to 
  director:changeScene("yourFirstScene") -- call next class(make sure the class exist)
  return parentGroup -- return 'parentGroup'
```

Comment: I have all that, and I have the error reports in the comments right under the question (they're really long). It seems to me, based off the reports, that there is a problem with the code in the director file.

Answer (score 1):

```
local main.lua = require ("main.lua")
```

So that is your code.
Do not type that, type this

```
local main = require ("main.lua")
```