# Lua/Corona EOF Error

Tags: lua, coronasdk, eof

(This continues from my first question.)

This is an EOF End of File error in which it says that an EOF was expected near my line 19, which you can see in the code below.

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
local director = {scene = 'main'}

function director:changeScene (moduleName)
    if type(moduleName) == 'nil' or self.scene == moduleName then return end

    local loadedModule = package.loaded[self.scene]
    if type(loadedModule) == 'table' and type(loadedModule.clean) == 'function' then
        loadedModule.clean()
    end

    if self.view then self.view:removeSelf() end

    if self.scene ~= 'main' and type(loadedModule) == 'table' then
        package.loaded[self.scene], self.view, loadedModule = nil
        collectgarbage('collect')
    end

    self.view, self.scene = require(moduleName).new(), moduleName
end

return director

local mainGroup = display.newGroup()       -- This is line 19
maingroup:insert(director.directorView)
director:changeScene("mainPage.lua")
return mainGroup
```

---

(If you didn't know, the director stuff is a way to manually access the file, that's not the problem in the code.)

The error is:
Line: 19

'' expected near 'local'
And line 19 is: local mainGroup = display.newGroup()

See my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083550/corona-simulator-syntax-error-unexpected-symbol) for a little background on the problem.

Comment: I would recommend adding a decent coding editor that understands Lua to your tool bag. [Zero Brane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) would be a good choice as it provides a debugger that can even do live coding with Corona apps, it is widely cross platform and does run on Mac, and it has a really good syntax and static analysis tool capability that will help prevent mistakes before they become bugs.

Answer (score 2):

After a `return` there can be no further statements: a `return` must be the last statement in a block.

But it seems to me that you forgot an `end` after that `return`.

Comment: I commented out the lines starting with the local mainGroup and got no error reports but a blank screen. Is this supposed to happen, because I thought it went to another page (I'm not sure, though.)

Comment: There seems to be an extra `end` before that return.

Comment: When I delete it, it says that the end is expected to close that function at line 4 near 'local'.

Comment: Do I not need the last 4 lines?

Comment: You do. Just swap end and return.

Comment: Oh dear...     Line: 20

Attempt to index global 'maingroup' (a nil value)

Comment: I reformatted your code fragment to show the blocks more clearly as Lua sees them. That shows that Lua sees the function as ending just above the `return director` and before `local mainGroup = `. To my eye, I agree with lhf that the `return director` belongs inside the function. But after that point it is all a Corona Framework question and I don't use Corona.